# Adding LTSpice directives

Tags: ltspice

What is an LTspice directive and how can you add it?
I am asked to set the simulation spice directive to a linear DC sweep between -10V and 10V with increments of 0.1V.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually called a SPICE directive, LTspice is software that provides an interface for SPICE.

Directives are just text, and they start with a period.
Here is an example directive called "step", with parameters after it: `.step X 1 10 100`

The default hotkey for creating a directive is <kbd>s</kbd>

You can also click the `.op` button as shown below:

[image: ltspice directive button]

When you first create a directive, a window opens up for you to type in.

[image: ltspice directive edit window]

After you've inserted it, you'll see it as text (default color is black) on the schematic.

[image: ltspice directive]

To re-edit the directive, right click on it. Note that some directives have their own special edit windows. If that's the case, right clicking on the directive will open a window with extra settings.

Directives can be disabled by turning them into a text comment. This is done by selecting `comment` in the edit window:

[image: ltspice directive comment]

Again, some directives have their own special edit windows. To turn those into a comment, you have to click `cancel` in the first window that pops up, and then you'll see the standard edit window with the comment option.

Comments appear as blue text by default. The following image shows a comment (blue) and a directive below it (black):

[image: ltspice directives and comments]

---

As for DC sweep,

Go to the toolbar `Simulate` > `Edit Simulation Cmd` and then click the `DC Sweep` tab. You can fill in your parameters there.

[image: ltspice simulation edit window]

Once you're finished editing the sweep parameters, the directive is created as text and you can place it anywhere on your schematic.